# Excel Dynamic operations for range

Tags: excel

I am preparing a test plan for a product , I want the summary report to be filled automatically when the test cases are updated.

I want to "=countifs(Fromcell:Tocell) , i want to have this range based on a criteria. Example if my range is A1 to A100 , I don't want to hardcode instead i would like excel to take the start cell if it contains START in the cell and the end cell if it contains END in it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose in your range `A1:A100` you put `Start` and `End` in cells as per your requirement.

Use MATCH to get start and end rows

```
D1 =MATCH("Start",$A$1:$A$100,)
D2 =MATCH("End",$A$1:$A$100,)
```

Now use this formula to get your count

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET($A$1,D1-1,0,D2-D1+1,1), your_criteria)
```

The `Offset()` part gives you the range between `Start` and `End` **inclusive of the two**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one single formula,

`=COUNTIF((INDIRECT("A"&MATCH("Start",A:A,0)):INDIRECT("A"&MATCH("End",A:A,0))),1)`

[image]

Where I am counting the value `1` between the `Start` and `End` in `Column A`. Hope this helps. Let me know if you face any difficulty.